Statistical sampling to remove data before fitting a model?
In normal circumstances, other things being equal, the more data we have, the better.
I am wondering about the following situation: I have a very large dataset and I want to fit a statistical model. However, my computer is not powerful enough to fit the model on the whole dataset.
Assuming each data point is equally reliable and has equal data quality, could I look into using statistical sampling to remove certain data points so that the model will run on my computer?
I think this could be quite complicated. Just as we use survey weights to account for ensure that no group of observations is underrepresented or overrepresented when building the dataset, is it possible to use similar techniques to ensure that reducing the size of the data has not resulted in any groups being over/under represented?
I think some logical checks will be needed to ensure that no over/under representation is present in the reduced dataset compared to the original data? E.g. If the original data has (60%-40% Men to Women), we would hope that the reduced dataset also roughly has a 20% difference in Men to Women. However, this is just one comparison method (e.g. after the reduction, the ratio of Men-Women is preserved, but the ratio of employed-unemployed is not preserved). Perhaps some general techniques exist to compare the difference between the joint distribution of two datasets (i.e. original vs reduced)?

Yes, you can do this, and it's often a good idea. It may even be that preliminary modelling shows that a project is a dead end. Everything hinges on what lies ahead: if this is for a higher degree, or a paper, or consultancy, at some point a supervisor, examiner, reviewer or client is probably going to ask why you didn't find a bigger computer to model the entire dataset.

That is a really good point, someone will probably ask why a better computer is not available. On the other hand, I am interested in learning about the theory behind such things .... is something like this possible? e.g. compare the mean and standard deviations of each variable between both datasets as a naive approach?

You can always compare the subset used with the subset used -- in principle. Comparing the subset with the set is fraught given the double counting.

@NickCox: did you mean "compare the subset used with the subset not used"?

Yes; sorry for any confusion.

It depends on the model.  Many will have a set of sufficient statistics that is much smaller than the size of the data.  An extreme example would be a binary question asked of a huge number $N$ of subjects: the data can be condensed to a single count of those who answered "yes."  Your computer is likely to be able to handle that!

Think of the situation in reverse.
Say you collected 50 observations, and then stopped because it was tedious, time consuming, or expensive (or too much for your computer). Can you analyze this data and run tests on it? Of course.
Is someone going to argue that you should have collected 100 observations? Maybe, as it would have been better; a more representative sample, higher power, etc. But does that mean that your sample of size 50 is non-representative? No, 100 would have been better, but 50 is not bad... Are your results based on the 50 observations biased or flawed? No, 100 would have been better, but...
So if collecting less than you might have been able to do is no mortal sin, using less than you actually have is equally no mortal sin. And, just as the "best" (least biased) way to collect additional data is random sampling, the "best" way to collect a subset is random sampling (as if you had only collected that many, to begin with).
